# Is putting class name in member routines redundant?

Tags: class, naming-conventions

Say you have a class Block...

```
class Block {
```

and it has a function that allows you to show the block on screen. Would you call it...

```
ShowBlock( ... )
```

or just

```
Show( ... )
```

This has been irking me, and I'd like to hear others thoughts. On one hand, ShowBlock is completely obvious whenever its used. However, since it will be called from a Block, it may be unnecessary like...

```
m_SomeBlock.ShowBlock( ... );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. The method is a member of the class so it becomes:

Block::Show()

The function becomes Show is a member of Block. If the method name was ShowBlock the it would be read as ShowBlock is a member of Block.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is more than redundant, it can be confusing unless you have a strict naming convention, for instance:

```
Block_Show();
Block_Draw();
Block_Whatever();
```

And your instantiation in the example already has "Block" in the name, so that should help another programmer when he/she needs more information on the method or class.